# OData query in SPD workflow HTTP GET request

Tags: 2013, workflow, web-services, rest, odata

I'm building a 2013 workflow that uses an OData query in an HTTP GET request that is intended to return a list of items with titles that begin with a certain string (which has previously been recorded in a variable). Here is the query so far:

```
http://server/site/subsite/_api/Lists/getbytitle('SomeList')/items?$filter=startswith(Title, '[%Variable: StringToMatch%]') eq true
```

Everything in the workflow works perfectly, but this request returns 0 items, despite there being several of them that do match the conditions. Can anyone spot the problem with the request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the "eq true" from your query.

```
http://server/site/subsite/_api/Lists/getbytitle('SomeList')/items?$filter=startswith(Title, '[%Variable: StringToMatch%]')
```

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100697/odata-substringof-or-startswith-returning-all-items

Comment: Bingo, thanks! I was going off of this site which has the eq true at the end of the example, that's why I was confused: http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-v2-documentation/uri-conventions/

Comment: I had heard the REST API was not 100% odata-compliant, maybe that's one of those cases :)